# Adding Git notes to a blob

Tags: git

I am trying to realize a use-case using git.

Use Case : It should be possible to add metadata (like Attributes) to git artifacts.

We plan to have a git repo for each component, so applying a note for each commit object could realize this requirement.

Now, it is also required that we have metadata for files within a component (git repo in this case). For this i tried to attach a note to a blob which was part of a commit.

It accepts the note and even I am able to push the notes to central repo.

Is this a safe and reliable usage of git notes for this use-case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2012: Yes, you can use [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) that way.

The blog post "[Git Tip of the Week: Git Notes](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-git-notes.html)" from [Alex Blewitt](https://twitter.com/alblue) reminds us about some of the `git notes` advantages and gotcha:

> the notes don’t have to be textual, nor do they have to be something which is mergeable.
> They don’t even need to be on the `notes/commits` ref; you can create notes based on any reference.
>
> In fact, this is how [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) works (which I’ve written about before).
> Gerrit stores its review information in the Git repository under notes/review. Ordinarily, this doesn’t show up (the git log only shows notes in the notes/commits refspace)
>
> - Git Notes are, in effect, a separate ‘branch’ of the repository (stored at `.git/refs/notes`)
> - merges: since the notes file is essentially on its own branch, the content doesn’t get merged with merges between branches. If you wanted to merge git notes, then following the `Key: Value` on separate lines is the way to achieve git note merging nirvana.

The ["note to self" article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112155416/http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html) also points out how pushing/pulling notes isn't exactly easy.

Beside those two issues (merging and pushing), you should be ok with your '`git notes`' use case.

---

Note: With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), avoid a stray empty newline in the template when creating new notes.

See [commit 3c9b01f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c9b01f0bf4f53eb8437bae725c854049a981865) (16 Nov 2022) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2fe427e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fe427ecb75167929b34ef340e9ee07ea1b57f2a), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`notes`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c9b01f0bf4f53eb8437bae725c854049a981865): avoid empty line in template
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Michael J Gruber</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When [`git notes`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3c9b01f0bf4f53eb8437bae725c854049a981865/Documentation/git-notes.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes))</sup> prepares the template it adds an empty newline between the comment header and the content:
>
> ```
> #
> # Write/edit the notes for the following object:
>
> # commit 0f3c55d
> # etc
> ```
>
> This is wrong structurally because that newline is part of the comment, too, and thus should be commented.
> Also, it throws off some positioning strategies of editors and plugins, and it differs from how we do commit templates.
>
> Change this to follow the standard set by [`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3c9b01f0bf4f53eb8437bae725c854049a981865/Documentation/git-commit.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup>:
>
> ```
> #
> # Write/edit the notes for the following object:
>
> # commit 0f3c55d
> ```
>
> Tests pass unchanged after this code change.

Comment: All progit.org links are dead.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Thank you for the feedback. I have restored all dead links for this 10 years-old answer.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if an issue about automatically using archive links is worth raising on the meta…

Comment: The question (as well as your answer) is almost evergreen in terms of its applicability, since unlike other parts of modern stack Git isn’t changing every week ;)

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff The ["web.archive.org" topic has been raised before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=web.archive.org), including [on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=web.archive.org).

Comment: Good to know I’m not alone in thinking this