# Is there a Git counterpart to svn:bugtraq properties?

Tags: git, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I'm looking for a specification or guidelines on how a Git client should integrate with bug tracking systems. For SVN, there are `bugtraq:`-properties. Is there something similar for Git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it seems that there currently is no such specification, I got that started:

https://github.com/mstrap/bugtraq

Comment: Interesting. +1. More detailed that my "git notes" proposal in my own answer.

Comment: "git notes" have been mentioned in the mailing list thread as well: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg218408.html ... I'm not sure what the client will be required to do, if we store bugtraq information in notes. If you have a proposal, feel free to comment the current specification or send me some pull request.

Answer (score 4):

You can put this in your /.git/config file to work with TortoiseGit:

```
[bugtraq]
    url = http://jira.com:8080/browse/
    number = false
    warnifnoissue = true
    message = http://jira.com:8080/browse/%BUGID%
    label = Issue number
    append = false
```

Comment: It's also possible to store this information inside the repository in `/.tgitconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) (which [I detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856913/6309)), in order to store on top of any regular commit a '`bugtrag`' note (in a `notes/bugtraq` namespace for instance).

That would allow an integration without rewriting the git repo history of commits already present.

Comment: Why duplicate the information - usually the commit message already contains the issue number.

Comment: OK, that's the way it could be stored. Though I think the commit message is sufficient (like it is in SVN). So I'm actually looking for a specification on *how to interpret* a commit message and extract issue IDs. Or how and where to store the URL of the issue tracker. Both is done using svn:bugtraq properties. If there is no counterpart in Git, maybe I should take this discussion to the Git mailing list?

Comment: @mstrap you put put any information you want in git notes. You can keep the issue ID in the commit message, and set the issue tracker url in a git notes. But there isn't a "standard" way of interfacing git with a bug tracker.

Answer (score -2):

integration of bug trackers with git usually works by parsing the git commit messages in the bug tracker.

i.e. you mention "fixes #1234" or "relates #1332" in your message and the bug tracker establishes the connection.

- e.g. redmine: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages
- e.g. github: https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the reverse direction: the Git client should start the interaction with the issue tracker.

Answer (score -2):

There's seldom a question that has not been asked before. There already is a popular standard for project information like the link to a bugtracker and much more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOAP (Description of a Project)

Comment: Thanks for the link, though I doubt DOAP will be applicable for this use case (or just for a fraction of what needs to be done). Have a look at TortoiseSVN's bugtraq documentation or https://github.com/mstrap/bugtraq. Specifying the interaction between a Git client and an issue tracker is more than storing an URL.